# Receive email from users in my gmail account when user submit the contact form in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am using laravel 7. I want to receive email from user in my gmail account when user submit the contact form. But when I submit the contact form, to and from addresses are same (i.e my gmail account).

My .env file

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=mygmail
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

My controller:

```php
public function saveContact(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required',
        'contact_no' => 'required',
        'message' => 'required',
    ]);

    $contact = new Contact();
    $contact->name = $request->name;
    $contact->email = $request->email;
    $contact->contact_no = $request->contact_no;
    $contact->message = $request->message;
    $contact->save();

    $data = array(
        'name' => $request->name,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'phone' => $request->contact_no,
        'user_message' => $request->message
    );

    Mail::to('mygmail')
        ->send(new ContactMail($data));

    return back()->with('success', 'Thank you for contacting us.');
}
```

My contactMail:

```php
public function build(Request $request)
{
    return $this->subject('New contact email')
        ->from($request->email)
        ->view('frontend.contact_email')
        ->with('data', $this->data);
}
```

What is wrong here? Because I am getting same to and from address. How do I receive message from users in my gmail account.

Comment: You can't do that, Gmail blocked that part. so you can only see your own gmail email on `from` address

Comment: Is there another way then?

Comment: use another SMTP provider like SendPlus, SMTP2Go

Comment: Will I then receive email in my gmail account

Comment: Yes. I am currently using SMTP2Go, and that send email on my Gmail

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: You just need to change  `MAIL_HOST,
MAIL_PORT,
MAIL_USERNAME,
MAIL_PASSWORD,
MAIL_ENCRYPTION` from your `.env` with new credential.

Comment: MAIL_USERNAME is my gmail account or smpt2go username??

Comment: smpt2go username

Comment: MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.smtp2go.com
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=smtp2gousername
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypass
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

Comment: But didn't work

Answer (score 1):

> You can't replace sender with `Google SMTP` service.

> Google rewrites the From and **Reply-To** headers in messages you send via it's `SMTP` service to values which relate to your gmail account.

**GMail** does allow sending via different addresses or alias but this is for sending via the **GMail web app**, see [Here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en)

If you own the domain you are supposedly sending from, use the [Gmail for Domains](https://gsuite.google.com/) , and setup a "*myapp@mydomain.com*" account. 
Or, use **another SMTP provider**

Comment: Mine is working fine. Would you check with mailtrap.io?

Comment: mailtrap.io works fine in localhost but not in server.

Comment: Also mailtrap.io doesn't send email to gmail.

Comment: I think i got the auth error in smtp2go. Let me try again and tell you the error

Comment: This is the error I get, Connection could not be established with host mail.smtp2go.com :stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number

Comment: Delete those lines from `config/mail.php` that you got another post answer.

Comment: Yes I have deleted.

Comment: Connection could not be established with host mail.smtp2go.com: stream_socket_client (): unable to connect to ssl: //mail.smtp2go.com: 2525 (Connection refused)

Comment: Try to change your port and encription. There are 4 alternative port for tls and 3 for ssl. One should work

Comment: Expected response code 354 but got code "503", with message "503-All RCPT commands were rejected with this error:
 503-that smtp username's account is not allowed to send
 503 Valid RCPT command must precede DATA
 "

Comment: Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username

Comment: My port 443 and encription is ssl

Comment: My port too is 443 and ssl but getting failed to authenticate on SMTP with username using 3 possible authenticators

Comment: You can get their chat support by live chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216582/discussion-between-talha-f-and-l0op).